# Pascal: "or" not supported for types "Char"

Tags: pascal

I'm new here so sorry if I do something wrong!

I'm making a simple Pascal program in Lazarus and I'm getting this error when compiling:

HWE(16,18) Error: Operation "or" not supported for types "Char" and "Constant String"

Here is the part it's complaining about:

```
Repeat
begin
Readln(style);
If style <> ('e' or 'mp' or 'sa') then
Writeln ('do what I say!')
end
Until style = (e or mp or sa);
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7):

`or` has to be used with Boolean expressions, like

```
(style <> 'e') or (style <> 'mp') or (style <> 'sa')
```

Answer (score 4):

Must use AND operator:

```
If (style <> 'e') AND (style <> 'mp') AND (style <> 'sa') then
```

*(Don't use OR operator in this case)*

Answer (score 2):

When combining two Boolean expressions using relational and Boolean operators, be careful to use parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice way in pascal to do this using Sets, but for ordinal types only (like CHAR, but NOT Strings):

```
if not(style in ['e', 'm', 'p']) then
  begin
  DoSomething;
  end
```

A very common use case I very often come across is to detect if a TDataSet is being edited:

```
if MyDataSet.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert] then
  Begin
  DoSomething;
  End;
```